# Get page titles from a list of URLS

Tags: shell, wget, title

I have list of URLS where I need to get the page titles saved in another list. wget or curl seems to be the right way, but I don't know exactly how. Can you help? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually I tried to combine 2 scripts I found on the net:

#!/bin/bash
while read LINE; do
  curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out "%{http_code} $LINE\n" "$LINE"
done < urllist.txt

| grep '<title>'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean something like that?

**wget_title_from_filelist.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r URL; do
    echo -n "$URL --> "
    wget -q -O - "$URL" | \
       tr "\n" " " | \
       sed 's|.*<title>\([^<]*\).*</head>.*|\1|;s|^\s*||;s|\s*$||'
    echo
done
```

**filelist.txt**

```
https://stackoverflow.com
https://cnn.com
https://reddit.com
https://archive.org
```

**Usage**

```
./wget_title_from_filelist.sh < filelist.txt
```

**Output**

```
https://stackoverflow.com --> Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, &amp; Build Careers
https://cnn.com --> CNN International - Breaking News, US News, World News and Video
https://reddit.com --> reddit: the front page of the internet
https://archive.org --> Internet Archive: Digital Library of Free &amp; Borrowable Books, Movies, Music &amp; Wayback Machine
```

**explanation**

```
tr "\n" " "     # remove \n, create one line of input for sed

sed 's|.*<title>\([^<]*\).*</head>.*|\1|;   # find <title> in <head>
s|^\s*||;                                   # remove leading spaces
s|\s*$||'                                   # remove trailing spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving [@utlox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11178750/utlox)'s answer to deal with title tags that have attributes (`<title k=v>`):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r URL; do
    echo -n "$URL --> "
    wget -q -O - "$URL" | \
       tr "\n" " " | \
       sed 's|.*<title[^>]*>\([^<]*\).*</head>.*|\1|;s|^\s*||;s|\s*$||'
    echo
done
```